# Architecture for Product rate assigning to multiple store group. C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am writting a module where i am creating a rate for a list of product, and the rate for the product are assigned to different Store.

The rate can be created in a group of Store, with Multiple Store, and Individual Store.

As shown in the image Below.

[image]

a. Group of Store

A Store group is selected from the list of group. The list of product are displayed where we set the rate for the products, the rate of the products will be tagged to Store which are tagged in the group

b. Multiple Store

The multiple store can be selected from the list and the rate are added to the store.

c. Individual Store

The rate for the product are assigned to a individual branch.

Enitity for Product Rate

```
public class ProductRate
{

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal MRP { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StoreId")]
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

}
```

Currently my implementation looks as following:

```
 public void CreateRateForIndividualStore(RateIndividualStoreViewModel model)
 {
     //Saving the rate of product
     // Maintaining history of the product rate in ProductRateHistory table
 }

 public List<string> RateForMultipleStore(RateMultipleStoreViewModel model)
 {
      //Saving the rate of product
     // Maintaining history of the product rate in ProductRateHistory table
 }

 public List<string> CreateRateByGroup(RateStoreGroupViewModel model)
 {

 }
```

Currently i am doing with the separate configuration for all three types.

ProductRateHistory table is the exact the same duplicate of the entity ProductRate.

Is there a more  generic way for doing this task? Any pre-defined design pattern or methods?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850330/architecture-for-product-rate-assigning-to-multiple-store-group-c-sharp "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat: I deleted the question on Stack Overflow.  It's been there two days with no activity.

Comment: @aakash: It's unclear what you're looking for.  At first glance, it all seems like the same problem: assigning rates to one or more stores.  A "group of store" is merely a filter.

Comment: In other words, I don't think you need three different ways to do this; you just need one.

Comment: In 'group of store' there will be only one group where multiple store are assigned, which are assigned when store is created. But in Multiple store user can select multiple store from the list.